# How to use Methods to solve: Locking account after three times?

Tags: java, loops, methods

I am trying to create a program that uses methods to lock/unlock an account.
Here is my program but when I am trying to run it, it says the parameter inside my methods for asking username and password cannot be empty.

I am a beginner and just learned how to use methods so if anyone can help explain what's the error with this program, that'd be great.

I am also trying to create a method for locking the account after three tries using loop but I am stuck with that. Please give some advice, thanks!

```
//Lock account after n=3 using methods
//using Methods created

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lock_Methods{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        String user_name = question();
        String pass_word = ask();

        int result = testing(user_name, pass_word);

        if (result == 0){
            System.out.println("Welcome");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Locked");


    } //end of main


    //2. method for asking username
    public static String question(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter username: ");
        String username = input.nextLine();

        return username;
    }

    //3. method for asking password
    public static String ask(String password){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
        password = input.nextLine();

        return password;

    }


    //4. method for testing whether username and password are true
    public static int testing(String inputname, String inputpw){
        int result = 0;
        String username = "edu";
        String password = "12345";

        if (!(username.equals(inputname)) || ! (password.equals(inputpw)))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;

        return result; //return statment

    }



} //end of class
```

Comment: `ask` method takes one `String` parameter but you invoke it without parameters. This will not work. Either pass the parameter when invoking the method or get rid of it. Second option seems more reasonable in context of what `ask` method should do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you explain more on "pass the parameter when invoking the method"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `String password` from `public static String ask(String password)`

When you are calling the ask method at `String pass_word = ask();` you are not passing any parameter in `ask()` but your method declaration has a parameter `String password` in it. Since you are not passing a parameter, it is giving you that error.

This is how your `ask()` method should be like:

```
public static String ask(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
    password = input.nextLine();

    return password;
}
```

As far as the three tries are of concern, try running this. I have made the changes mentioned above here as well so just run this and see if it works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lock {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        String user_name = question();
        String pass_word = ask();

        int count = 0;

        while (count < 4) {
            int result = testing(user_name, pass_word);

            if (result == 0) {
                System.out.println("Welcome");
            }
            count++;
        }

        if (count > 3) {
            System.out.println("Locked");
        }

    } //end of main 

    //2. method for asking username
    public static String question(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter username: ");
        String username = input.nextLine();

        input.close();

        return username;
    }

    //3. method for asking password
    public static String ask(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
        String password = input.nextLine();

        input.close();

        return password;

    }


    //4. method for testing whether username and password are true
    public static int testing(String inputname, String inputpw){
        int result = 0;
        String username = "edu";
        String password = "12345";

        if (!(username.equals(inputname)) || ! (password.equals(inputpw)))
            result = 1;

        return result; //return statment

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That clarifies a lot.
I was trying to create a method for this locking account, but I am not sure what the return statement should be in this case.
 public static String test (String password){
  for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
   if (! (password.equals("12345"))){
    count++;
    System.out.println("Try again");
   
   }
   else {
    System.out.println("Welcome");
    break;
   }

  }

Comment: Instead of giving the test method a return type of String, make it a boolean: `public static boolean test (String password)`. Initialize a variable `boolean isLocked = false`. Make this change `if (! (password.equals("12345"))){ isLocked = true; System.out.println("Try again"); } else { isLocked = false; break; }` and return `isLocked` at the end of your method.

You will receive a `true` or `false` value during method call and run an if statement to print relevant message